# Executing rundll32.exe with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, windows, dll, createprocess, rundll32

I've created a DLL and would like to execute one of the functions using the rundll32.exe command on windows.

Using rundll32.exe, it runs correctly from the command line; however, I'd like to call it (rundll32.exe) from a separate program. I cannot directly call the function from my code due to 32/64 bit compatibility issues in the underlying libraries I'm using (Easyhook).

Below is what I'm using in an attempt to run the dll function:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi));

LPCTSTR application = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe";
LPTSTR cmd = "C:\\Projects\\Test\\mydll.dll,MyFunc";

BOOL cpRes = CreateProcess(application,
  cmd,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  FALSE,
  0,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  &si,
  &pi);

if(cpRes == 0) {
  cout << "ERROR\n";
  cout << GetLastError() << endl;
} else {
  cout << "DLL Launched!" << endl;
}

CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

The output to my console is always `DLL Launched`; however, I do not see the effects of my DLL actually being called (currently stubbed out in such a way that the command writes to a file).

If I swap out the application with something such as `C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe`, the program successfully runs.

For completion, here's the body of `MyFunc`:

```
ofstream file;
file.open("C:\\Projects\\Test\\test.txt");
file << "I wrote to a file!";
file.close();
```

Is there any reason CreateProcess cannot be used with rundll32? While reading over this I found several warnings about `LoadLibrary()` and `DLLMain` but it doesn't *seem* like they're relevant to this.

---

More Clarification:
This is currently a 32-bit application (allegedly) launching the 32-bit `rundll32.exe` (Logic will be added later to call the 32 or 64 bit version).

My dll is as follows:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void CALLBACK MyFunc(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);

void CALLBACK MyFunc(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow) { ... }
```

Which also has a `.def` file with:

```
EXPORTS
  MyFunc
```

Running

```
C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe C:\Projects\Test\mydll.dll,MyFunc
```

produces the expected results.

---

**Update**
Setting `application` to `NULL` and including the `rundll32.exe` in cmd as mentioned in the comments seems to work.

Relevant Docs:
[CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)
[RunDll32.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164787/info-windows-rundll-and-rundll32-interface)

Comment: What is the output of `cout << GetLastError() << endl;` when DLL is not launched properly?

Comment: @NaseefUrRahman The output is [0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: What is the exact signature of the function you're trying to call from the DLL?

Comment: Does `rundll32` bitness match your dll bitness?

Comment: exec `rundll32.exe mydll.dll,MyFunc` direct under debugger and view what is going wrong

Comment: @RbMm It exports correctly as MyFunc for 32 bit as seen when I use DependencyWalker and simply running it from the command line.

Comment: @user5786682 - did not notice def file. yes, in this case will de undecorated name (but for what you use also `__declspec(dllexport)` in this case ?). anyway you need in debugger run run32dll with you command line and look

Comment: Are you sure the DLL is not actually being called?  Maybe the DLL is having trouble accessing its output file instead. I would suggest changing the DLL function to do something a bit more noticeable, llke calling `OutputDebugString()` (which you can view using [SysInternals DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview)) or `MessageBox()`

Comment: use `LPTSTR cmd = "rundll32.exe C:\\Projects\\Test\\mydll.dll,MyFunc";` as command line

Comment: @RbMM It's very possible I do not need __declspec(ddlexport) This is my first attempt at a DLL and I had read that I needed it. I'll see what I can find with a debugger.

Comment: change the command line - add exe name (without path) in the front

Comment: @RbMm: if you do this, it is better to get rid of the `application` parameter altogether, just pass NULL to it, and then specify the full application path in the `cmd` parameter: `TCHAR cmd[] = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe C:\\Projects\\Test\\mydll.dll,MyFunc"; CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, ...);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - use application parameter is good and not need set to 0. however some program, when parsing command line assume that first token is exe name. the presense of applicationname not change this

Comment: @RbMm: I'm well aware of that. But if you set `application` to NULL, `CreateProcess()` handles passing the module name in the first command line argument for you. This is [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - the command line always passed to child as is, how we set it in call. use or not use *lpApplicationName* not affect this. simply if we use *lpApplicationName* it is used. if 0 here - api get it from command line

Comment: @RbMm Switching it to just use the cmd line arguments seems to work!

Comment: PS: [What’s the guidance on when to use rundll32? Easy: Don’t use it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) documentation:

> If both `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by `lpApplicationName` specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by `lpCommandLine` specifies the command line. The new process can use `GetCommandLine` to retrieve the entire command line. Console processes written in C can use the `argc` and `argv` arguments to parse the command line. **Because `argv[0]` is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line**.

You are not repeating `rundll32.exe` as the first command-line token.

So, if you continue using the `lpApplicationName` parameter, then change this:

```
LPCTSTR application = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe";
LPTSTR cmd = "C:\\Projects\\Test\\mydll.dll,MyFunc";
```

To this instead:

```
LPCTSTR application = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe");
LPTSTR cmd = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe C:\\Projects\\Test\\mydll.dll,MyFunc");
```

Note that you are currently compiling for ANSI/MBCS (by virtue of the fact that you are passing narrow strings to `CreateProcess()`). If you ever update the project to compile for Unicode, use this instead:

```
TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe C:\\Projects\\Test\\mydll.dll,MyFunc");
```

This is because the documentation states:

> *lpCommandLine* [in, out, optional]
>   ...
>   The Unicode version of this function, `CreateProcessW`, can modify the contents of this string. **Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory** (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

You might consider changing `cmd` into a `TCHAR[]` array anyway, even in ANSI/MBCS, so you can do something like this:

```
LPCTSTR application = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe");

TCHAR cmd[(MAX_PATH*2)+10];
wsprintf(cmd, TEXT("%s %s,%s"), application, TEXT("C:\\Projects\\Test\\mydll.dll"), TEXT("MyFunc"));
```

Either way, by passing the module filename as the first token in the `lpCommandLine` parameter, you can then set the `lpApplicationName` parameter to NULL:

> The `lpApplicationName` parameter can be NULL. In that case, the module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the `lpCommandLine` string.

Let `CreateProcess()` setup the correct command-line to pass to `rundll32.exe` for you:

```
TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe C:\\Projects\\Test\\mydll.dll,MyFunc");

BOOL cpRes = CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, ...);
```

Comment: if we use *lpApplicationName* (!=0) we can add *any* token to *lpCommandLine*. not mandatory full path. even not name. any string(without space is ok). so say `@ C:\\Projects\\Test\\mydll.dll,MyFunc` will be work too. and if we *have* exactly *lpApplicationName* always better use pass it to `CreateProcess`

Comment: Good answer overall, but if you're going to suggest using `TCHAR cmd[] = ...`, then you should also use the `TEXT` macro around the string literal, as in `TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("C:\\Windows....\\mydll.dll,MyFunc");`.  The alternative is to explicitly use `WCHAR` and the `L` prefix.

Comment: @RbMm by convention, `argv[0]` is expected to be a FULL path to the calling process. Sure, you can pass just the module name by itself, but you would break any console app that needs a full path. Maybe `rundll32` doesn't. Don't risk it.

Comment: also if pass path or even name in command line, need enclose it in "", for case when path or name containing space.